# Issue with pressed state of icon buttons on ActionBar - AppCompat 24.0.0

Tags: android

[image]

It seems that the issue is caused by 9patch background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by Gradle version `2.2.0-alpha3`, just down to use `2.1.0` and it works fine again.

Comment: This is confusing, I was scared that they dropped 9patch support :)